# Dynamic mutation document for react-apollo

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I need to change my mutation document dynamically to be able to create multiple items in a single mutation. So I have this function `createOrderName` that takes an integer and be able to create the correct mutation document. Eg. `createOrderName(2)` gets

```
mutation createOrderMut($input0: AddToOrderMenuItemConnectionInput!, $input1: AddToOrderMenuItemConnectionInput!) {
  input0: addToOrderMenuItemConnection (input:$input0) {
    changedOrderMenuItem {
      id
    }
  }
  input1: addToOrderMenuItemConnection (input:$input1) {
    changedOrderMenuItem {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

And my container is as follow.

```
const CartContainer = compose(
  graphql(createOrderName(2), {
    props: ({ mutate }) => ({
      addToOrderMenuItem: (menus, orderId) => mutate({
        variables: createOrdersInput(menus, orderId)
      })
    })
  })
)(CartView)
```

Now how can I pass an integer value to this mutation in order for it to create the correct mutation document? Currently it's fix to 2, but I need it to be more flexible so I can create any number of items...

Comment: Why not send a separate mutation request for each order?

Comment: That would be too expensive time wise, For example if there's an order with 500 items, it would take 500 network calls. whereas with this its done in just 1 network transaction.

Comment: I think in this case you should use `withApollo` to use `client.mutate` directly, and dynamically generate the query string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like an unfortunate limitation of the backend you're working with. The right way to do a batch mutation would be to have a single mutation field on the server that accepts a list argument with all of the items you want to insert. Thus, Apollo isn't designed to support such dynamic query generation with the standard `react-apollo` API. That's because we strongly believe that working with static queries is much better than generating fields at runtime: https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/5-benefits-of-static-graphql-queries-b7fa90b0b69a#.hp710vxe7

Given the situation, though, sounds like generation the mutation string dynamically is a good option. You can do this by using Apollo directly instead of through the `graphql` HoC. You can use the `withApollo` HoC to do this: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/higher-order-components.html#withApollo

```
import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo';

const MyComponent = ({ client }) => {
  function mutate() {
    const dynamicMutationString = // generate mutation string here

    client.mutate({
      mutation: gql`${dynamicMutationString}`,
      variables: { ... },
    }).then(...);
  }

  return <button onClick={mutate}>Click here</button>;
}

const MyComponentWithApollo = withApollo(MyComponent);
```

We built this extra API for just this purpose - when the standard stuff is not enough.

Here are the docs for `mutate` btw: http://dev.apollodata.com/core/apollo-client-api.html#ApolloClient.mutate

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I can answer your question with your current implementation, so I'm going to urge you to rethink your mutation definition and use `GraphQLList` and `GraphQLInputObject`.

So, depending on the fields you need to mutate:

```
args: {
  input: {
    type: new GraphQLList(new GraphQLInputObjectType({
      name: 'inputObject',
      description: 'Your description here',
      fields: {
        id: { type: GraphQLInt }
      },
    })),
  },
},
```

This way you can provide n-number of objects into your mutate call, and get a list back on your type:

```
{
  mutation myMutation {
    addToOrderMenuItemConnection(input: [{ id: 123 }, { id: 456 }]) {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Again, I'm not 100% familiar with your end-goal, but I think this would give you flexibility for future changes/updates as well since you're dealing with an object input rather than individual arguments, which would also (hopefully) insulate you from future breaking-changes.

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't realise there's `GraphQLList`. I'm going to try it out and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is really on the server side of things. I'm asking about the client side. I don't have control of the server side as I'm using a GraphQL service. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is the right answer, perhaps the service can add it for you? I know they can be pretty responsive to requests like this.