# How to structure a GraphQL mutation when dealing with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I am using Apollo Client and trying to build a mutation that submits an object, part of that object is an array of a subtype, this array needs to be dynamic in size but I cannot find any documentation on how to correctly build this.

This is my mutation with a manually typed array and this works fine.

```
const SET_TEMPLATE = gql`
mutation setTemplate( 
    $id: String,
    $name: String, 
    ) {
    setTemplate(
        id: $id
        input: {
            name: $name
        }
        data: [
            {
                name: "Branded"
                format: "String"
                canExpand: false
                data: {}
            },
            {
                name: "Assigned User"
                format: "String"
                canExpand: false
                data: {}
            },
            {
                name: "Assigned Users"
                format: "String"
                canExpand: false
                data: {}
            }
        ]) {
        name
        author
        data {
            name
            format
            data
        }
    }
}
`
```

The below is pseudo for what I want to achieve.

```
const SET_TEMPLATE = gql`
mutation setTemplate( 
    $id: String,
    $name: String, 
    $data: FieldInput 
    ) {
    setTemplate(
        id: $id
        input: {
            name: $name
        }
        data: [
            $data
        ]) {
        name
        author
        data {
            name
            format
            data
        }
    }
}
`
```

Should I be following something like this, or is there an easier way? [Dynamic mutation document for react-apollo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41993034/dynamic-mutation-document-for-react-apollo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible,
you just have a slight problem in you mutation variable decleration. 
Instead of `$data: FieldInput` declare it as `$data: [FieldInput]`. 
The resulting query of what you'll want to achieve will look like this:

```
const SET_TEMPLATE = gql`
mutation setTemplate( 
    $id: String,
    $name: String, 
    $data: [FieldInput]
    ) {
    setTemplate(
        id: $id
        input: {
            name: $name
        }
        data: $data) {
        name
        author
        data {
            name
            format
            data
        }
    }
}
`
```